# How to remove few characters from a String

Tags: apex, string

I have a string value where I am getting the a comma with `}` I want to remove the last `,` I have tried below but it is not working.

```
String str = '{johny:[1,2,3,4,5],erich:[5,6,7,8,9],}';
system.debug('strValue: ' + str.Substring(str.length()-2));
```

or tried this:

```
system.debug('strValue: ' + str.substring(1,str.length()-1););
```

result should be like this (without comma at the end):

```
String str = '{johny:[1,2,3,4,5],erich:[5,6,7,8,9]}';
```

Comment: But why is that extra comma there anyways? It's not proper JSON...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String str = '{johny:[1,2,3,4,5],erich:[5,6,7,8,9],}';
system.debug('strValue: ' + str.left(str.length()-2)+str.right(1));
```

yields

```
strValue: {johny:[1,2,3,4,5],erich:[5,6,7,8,9]}
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use replace method of  [String Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_replace)

for you case use:

```
str.replace(',}','}');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to strip off the last character, this will work

```
String str = '{johny:[1,2,3,4,5],erich:[5,6,7,8,9],}';
system.debug('strValue: ' + str.left(str.length()-2));
```

Comment: this will delete the 2 characters